# Automate the Default Program Association

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm Writing a batch script to automate the process of changing default program association for specific file types.

The file types are defined perfectly and i'm using this command to change default program for opening them for example:

```
ftype giffile="%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" "%1"
```

But after running this, nothing will change!

"giffile" is just an example of file type that i'm trying to change default program association.

What am i missing ? (suggestions would be great if there is a better solution)

> EDIT: with `ftype` i could just be able to add the program to the "open with" list and that doesn't change default program used to open specific filetype.

Comment: A `reg.exe` alternative: `@"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\giffile\shell\Open\command" /VE /D "\"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\" \"%%~1\"" /F>NUL`. However you've given us absolutely no information to base answers upon, as we have no idea what nothing will change! means. Is that because of the permissions? because you haven't restarted/refreshed the registry? who knows? Considering we aren't sat at your PC, and this is a system configuration change, not many people will want to just blindly run that command to debug things for you. Please clarify matters.

Comment: Ashkan, I could simply replicate the above as an answer, but I'm reluctant to do so because it is only part of a solution, and I would not be confident that future readers would understand that, on its own, it may well achieve nothing. My comment was an alternative only to `FType` which was usually a follow on from an `Assoc` command. It is also specific to the current user and not all users, _because nobody should be modifying these things globally_. My comment is only part of the association therefore and requires to be partnered with an entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.gif`

Comment: I have edited the post hopefully i could make it more understandable!
i think the edit part would clarify the problem!
Also for reg.exe alternative you said i could't still change default program!

Comment: Your edit hasn't changed my view I'm afraid. There is no indication that any class has associated an extension to the filetype before assigning a command to open it. In the above case, for example, there is no indication that `chrome.exe` exists on that system, or in fact if it is installed to the directory you're attributing to it. I would never write a batch file to modify the registry with that line without verifying those things first. It is even less wise, were you to consider that a program may be installed on the system but not for that specific user, so drive searches are pointless.

Comment: Additional to that, I want my files to open in the programs I decide, not those decided by somebody with a batch file. Therefore even you had satisfied the things in my previous comment, the script would also need to back up any existing registry entries before modifying them. It would also need a robust uninstall procedure in place to check whether the entries were still those as installed by your script, and if so return them to their previous values, but only if those values haven't been associated elsewhere to something by the edd user in the interim period because of your changes.

Comment: Well let me explain, i'm doing this because i'm trying to "Activate Windows Photo Viewer on Windows 10" and use it instead of "Photos" application, i've found the solution by editing registry.
Also i had to use GUI to set it as default program! 
so it came up to my mind that i could write an script to simply do that!
and "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" is an address to a file that all of my windows machines that i'm trying to run already has it!
So by doing this i could give my script to my unprofessional friends and simplify the process for them.

Comment: AshKan, at your own risk, you are free to use the example in my initial comment, if it works for your specific purposes, but I'm not posting it as an answer, because I'm not satisfied that it is safe advice for other/future readers.

Comment: Actually after testing your reg alternative i found out that it acts like ftype just like you said in a comment.
and the problem isn't solved by the way because ftype or the alternatives just add the application to "open with" list and and doesn't change the default program!
thank you for comments, you made me more clear in asking my question!

Comment: Well that also depends upon the porgram, whether it is a user or machine setting and whether other things like program IDs, CLSIDs, persistent handlers, and other things are in place. As I said, it is not wise to modify the registry in this way. The best idea is to allow the end user to perform their own file associations using the OS GUI or alternative specifically built software, with robustness built in.

Comment: @Compo actually i'm not disagree but i think robustness is not the case of using automated batch file that is created to do things just automatically without user's choice!

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm will that change default program for opening specific filetype ?

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm, just for clarification, I do hope that you're not suggesting that there's anything at all wrong with the way I used `reg.exe` in my initial comment!

Comment: I didn't refer to your comment at all!

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm, please remember to address other members correctly, so that they know you've responded directly to them. I asked because I posted the only `reg.exe` code. In the OP's comment, directly above yours, they said "Actually after testing your reg alternative", _(mine)_, "and the problem isn't solved by the way". Then you responded with "Using reg.exe in a right way should do the job", this certainly implies that my way, was not the right way, doesn't it?

Comment: You need to use `assoc` together with `ftype`. See [Assoc - File extension and Type - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill, Actually that would only change association between a file extension and filetype that is not my case unfortunately!
i'm seeking for a way that could change default program associated to a file type!
and the problem is that `ftype` seems not working properly on windows 10 or maybe just this is not the case that `ftype` is for!

Answer (score 1):

Oh that is a good one, and it took me several hours to find the misbehaviour. To test this, I refer to the .txt file.
Problem is, as far as I figured, that your datatype is already opened with another **system-internal** program. In my case, .txt is connected to Worpad. So if you mess around with the registry (nothing else is assoc and ftype doing), it will always fallback to Wordpad, no matter what. Even changing it to another program as you try, it will fallback.

In order to verify this bevaviour you can simply think of a new (unconnected) fileextension and try your program association with it. For example .log was not associated for my system, so doing the following steps for a .log file immediately changed its opening program the way I wanted. If log is already connected for you, think of something comepletely new.

So **Step1 is to not let it fallback to Wordpad**. As Wordpad is an Optional Feature of Windows, we first have to uninstall it. This is easiest in Software->Programs->Optional Features and select it there to be uninstalled.
As you prefer a programatical way with a batch script i can recommend the dism command, which can be reversed by replacing "Remove" with "Add".

```
dism /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.WordPad~~~~0.0.1.0
```

After this, if you doubleclick a txtfile it will not be opened by default anymore.
Then, as stated in many different answers to this question, all you need to change a filextension to behave as you wish is to call

```
assoc .txt
```

That will give you "txtfile" as return value. Then connecting the txtfile type with the program you wish to have it opened type. Make sure it is txtfile and not textfile. Im a bit confused which of both it was for me, I think the windows standard is txtfile. Typos can be ugly here.

```
ftype txtfile="exampleprogram.exe" "%1"
```

- Please remember here, that in batch you need to use %%1 because the first % is escaped. If that %1 is omitted, the program starts on doubleclick but will not present the acutal opened file.
- The quotes are only used because most programs have a space in their filepath.
- My example deinstalls the Wordpad. While it should not be problem to redirect all filetypes to the program you with to replace .txt with, remember that .bat, and .ini files are per default also opened by Wordpad, maybe some more.

I included the txtfile example as this worked for me and you clearly stated the giffile is just an example. Adaption to your giffile difference is to get rid of the photos app first. Research says this can be also be done programatically.